# Is it possible in slack bot to create textual links back to the bot

Tags: ruby, bots, slack-api, slack

I have successfully deployed a slack bot using https://github.com/slack-ruby/slack-ruby-client

My bot can responds to a long list of commands. I would like some commands to return a "link" to a different command.

So for instance I might have something like:

`Me: Bot do_operation_one arguments=....`

The bot will return a response

`Bot: "Result for operation one with arguments..."`

Then I might chain that response to a different command, something like:

`Bot do_operation_two arguments="Result_for_operation_one"`

It would be much more convenient if the bot could return results with links to other operations that include the necessary parameters which can invoke operation_two/operation_three etc. without the need to type it.

In my particular case I am returning from my bot a list of versions from the bot:

`Me: bot list version`

`Bot: 1.0,1.1,1.2,1.3,.....`

Ideally each version could have other operations to apply on it , using the version as the parameter:

`Bot: 
1.0: link_operation1, link_operation2, link_operation3 ...
1.1: link_operation1, link_operation2, link_operation3 ...
1.2: link_operation1, link_operation2, link_operation3 ...`

Is this possible in a slack bot?

Answer (score 0):

Technically its possible to provide links for calling those "different commands", but I believe there is a better solution.

You can of course include dynamically created HTML links in your response and connect them to your script but there are two issues with that approach:
1) Those links will always be GET requests, so all context information included in those links (e.g. user id) will be visible to the the user. This can be a security concern. There is a whole discussion on this topic, but one solution could be to encrypt all parameters in your URL.
2) Clicking on the link will always open a browser window that will need to be manually closed again by the user. This does not have to be a show stopper, but it might confuse and/or annoy some users.

Because of those issues I would suggest another approach that would be more secure and user friendly.

Instead of providing links I would suggest to provide the list of suggested "different commands" either as [message buttons](https://api.slack.com/docs/message-buttons) or [message menu](https://api.slack.com/docs/message-menus).

Since there appear to be quite a few suggested "different commands" I believe a dynamically generated drop-down list of all "different commands" would work best.